# Highlight consecutive repeated values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sorted list

```
btn.pchome.net
btn.pchome.net
circle01.com
click.gamersky.com
click.gamersky.com
click.gamersky.com
db5.gamersky.com
doubleclick.net
doubleclick.net
doubleclick.net
googleads.g.doubleclick.net
googleads.g.doubleclick.net
googleads.g.doubleclick.net
googleads.g.doubleclick.net
```

I want to highlight consecutive entries that repeat at least 3 times. If two groups of consecutive repeated entries are adjacent, they should be highlighted with different color.

[image]

This figure demonstrates the desired result. The group of doubleclick.net and the group of googleads.g.doubleclick.net cannot be highlighted with the same color.

It's up to you whatever highlight colors are used.

Basically I only want to highlight items that duplicate at least N times. That's why in my example btn.pchome.net is not highlighted.

Comment: Excel has the highlight duplicate rule.  You can use that.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah, but I only want to highlight items that duplate at least N times. That's why in my example btn.pchome.net is not highlighted.